# infinite loop in simple mips

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to learn about $ra, so the output I want is "mainfunction1main" , by main calling function1, function1 returning to main, and main finishing. but for some reason I'm getting an infinite loop which prints "mainfunction1mainfunction1......" what am I doing wrong?

```
    .data
mainstring: .asciiz "main"  
string1: .asciiz "function1"
string2: .asciiz "function2"
string3: .asciiz "function3"

.text

main:   la $a0,mainstring
        li $v0, 4
        syscall

        jal function1

        la $a0, mainstring
        syscall

function1: la $a0, string1
            syscall
            jr $ra
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like JasonD said, you need to exit your program at the end of main. All you need to do is append two lines at the end of main, like so:

```
main:
    # ... previous stuff

    li $v0, 10                                                                                                                                                               
    syscall
```

This will load and run the `exit` system call (which has a code of 10.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to return at the end of main. At the moment you'll just fall through to function1 again, which will jump back to main, and then fall through again, etc...